# How to pass session key user_id to "Select from" sql statement

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

im now to php so dont be alarmed if my code is appalling. I was wondering if anyone knew the correct way to write this statement?

```
$query = "SELECT age,smoker,drinker FROM profile WHERE user_id ='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'" ;
```

my full code from the two pages is below

```
<?php 
session_start();
  $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbgroup19');
  $name = "";
  $password = "";

  if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
      $name = $_POST['name'];

      $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql_i = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE name = '$name'";
    $sql_u = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name'";
    $sql_e = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE password='$password'";
    $res_i = mysqli_query($db, $sql_i);
    $res_u = mysqli_query($db, $sql_u);
    $res_e = mysqli_query($db, $sql_e);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($res_u) < 1) {
        $name_error = "username doesnt exist";
      }
        elseif (mysqli_num_rows($res_e) < 1) {
            $password_error = "incorrect password";
        }
    else{
        $_SESSION["user_id"] = $user_id;
        $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
        header("location:displayprofile.php");
    }
  }
?>
```

```
<?php include('editprofileredirect.php');
session_start();


$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbgroup19');
$user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];


$query = "SELECT age,smoker,drinker FROM profile WHERE user_id ='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'" ;
$results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Display all records from Database</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Employee Details</h2>

<table border="2">
  <tr>
    <td>Sr.No.</td>
    <td>Full Name</td>
    <td>Age</td>
  </tr>


<?php
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $data['age']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['smoker']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['drinker']; ?></td>
  </tr> 
<?php
}
?>
</table>

<br>
<form method="post" action="editprofileredirect.php" id="redirect_form">
<button type="submit" name="editprofile" id="edit_btn">add to or edit profile</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's wrong with the statement as you've provided it? If you are getting errors please [edit] your question and include the complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code is open to SQL Injection. You better check this out:

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-querying-data-from-mysql-table/

You can use the following version:

```php
<?php
  session_start();
  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbgroup19", 'root', '');
  $name = "";
  $password = "";

  if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];

      $q = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ?');
      $q->execute([$name]);
      $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      $result = $q->fetch();

      if (empty($result)) {
        $name_error = "username doesnt exist";
      } elseif ($result['password'] != $password) {
            $password_error = "incorrect password";
      }
      else{
        $_SESSION["user_id"] = $result['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['name'] = $result['name'];
        // You don't need password in session.
        header("location:displayprofile.php");
    }
  }
?>
```